# What is ManageController.cs in ASP.NET-MVC 5.1 and why it was created? It haven't been created by MVC's 5.1 template before

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5.1

In June I started ASP.NET-MVC **5.1**  project. I finished it in October and now I wanted to start a new one. Same version of ASP.NET-MVC. I selected new project->....->MVC with Individual Accounts exactly like before.

Just at the start I noticed in Controller directory 3 controllers(not 2 as few months ago): `AccountController`, `HomeController` and **`ManageController`** and in Views `ManageViewModels`.

What is `ManageController`?

Why it appeared despite I write new application in exacly the same version of MVC as before?

Can I force Visual Studio 2013 to use the previous template?(I am not sure if I want that but asking in case I do)

**Old(plus mine additional controllers)**:

[image]

**New**:

[image]

Comment: This came with the new visual studio I believe. Did you also install the preview of VS 2015?

Comment: @BradChristie Not yet and I don't know if I want to install it because I would like to stick to ASP.NET MVC 5  and not go into vNext yet(I don't know if 2015 supports MVC 5 also I will wait for final version). I have installed Update 3 to VS 2013 and now I am going to install Update 4.  Back to the topic. do you know what this `ManageController.cs` does differently then before?

Comment: I have update 3 as well, so that may be the culprit (in terms of what provided the new template).

Answer (score 4):

When Visual Studio 2013 was first released, it was released with ASP.NET Identity 1.0, and the default template included the two controllers you mention.

At some point, I think Update 2, they upgraded the version of ASP.NET Identity that comes with Visual studio to 2.0, and in Update 3 they upgraded this to 2.1.  Identity 2.1 comes with the new Sign-in manager, which you can read about here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/05/announcing-rtm-of-asp-net-identity-2-1-0.aspx

ManageController deals with this signin manager, and was added to the default template.

Answer (score 4):

ManageController is for an authenticated user to manage her account.
If you visit this link:

http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity

you'll find screenshots on how it works.